# Python 3 selenium при использовании driver.get(ссылка) открывает ссылку фокусируется на окне браузера как не фокусироваться на окне

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-10

При работе в windows 10 в коде написано driver.get(ссылка), при ее выполнении, если я работаю с другими программами или к примеру смотрю фильм, постоянно фокусируется на webdriver.

Есть ли функция для driver.get(ссылка), чтобы принудительно не фокусировалась?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, можно использовать агрумент `--headless`, который не открывает окно браузера вовсе. Нет окна - нет проблем :) Может, такой вариант Вам подойдёт?

Comment: хочется смотреть иногда что программа делает на каком этапе